# Using shinyWidgets for fileInput button

Tags: r, shiny

All of the buttons in a shiny app I am making use `shinyWidgets`. I also use a fileInput button and I would like the button of this to be in the same style as my `shinyWidgets::actionBttn`. Is there a way of doing this?

```
library(shiny)
library(shinyWidgets)

shinyUI(fluidPage(

  # Application title
  titlePanel("Uploac a file"),

  fileInput("Myfile",label="",multiple = FALSE),br(),
  actionBttn("textPrep",label = "Browse")
))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do something like this:

```
library(shiny)
library(shinyWidgets)
library(shinyjs)

ui <- fluidPage(
  useShinyjs(),

  # Application title
  titlePanel("Upload a file"),

  fileInput("Myfile", label="", multiple = FALSE), 
  br(),
  actionBttn("textPrep", label = "Browse")
)

server <- function(input, output){
  addCssClass(class = "bttn bttn-unite bttn-default bttn-no-outline", 
              selector = ".btn-file")
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```